# Separated Java EE and PHP APIs running in the same machine and sharing the same SQL database general workaround

Tags: php, java, sql

Having in mind the Java EE and the PHP APIs are completely separated (this is not about using java processes from PHP or PHP processes from java) and they will only share the database, is there any key issue, specific configuration, install order or any possible variable that I should have in mind?

I've installed and run PHP, Java EE and SQL servers in my local machines (OSX and Windows) but I'm asking in case I should consider something important when installing the production server (Linux).

Apart, and knowing in advance this can be subjective, any recommendation for a simple install of both platforms in the same machine?

Comment: There is nothing to worry about. Just install them and use them.

Comment: Ok, loks like there is really no issue :)